# Sorting By Retrogression

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

So I have this very interesting computing problem I need to solve and can't seem to come up with a great answer. So I am in charge of the programming for a golf application that manages golf tournaments. Now after I have my list of players sorted by their scores, their is another step that needs to be done. Any ties need to be broken through something called retrogression. Which in short is, to determine who wins retrogression between two players, the best back nine wins, if that does not solve the dispute, then we start from hole 18 and work our way back, until a player has won outright on a hole. So I've created a method that can determine from two players who wins retrogression (the code is included below). Now my question is I have a large list with all the players in them, and I need to sort by retrogression any and all ties greater then 2 peoples. Any idea how I can do this with what I have now? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static PlayerScoreEntry winnerByRetro(PlayerScoreEntry p1, PlayerScoreEntry p2){
    if(p1.getAbsoluteBackNine() > p2.getAbsoluteBackNine()){
        return p2;
    }else if(p1.getAbsoluteBackNine() < p2.getAbsoluteBackNine()){
        return p1;
    }else{
        for(int a = 17; a >= 0; a--){
            int p1Int = Integer.parseInt(p1.holes[a].getText());
            int p2Int = Integer.parseInt(p2.holes[a].getText());

            if(p1Int > p2Int){
                return p2;
            }else if(p2Int > p1Int){
                return p1;
            }
        }

        return p1;
    }
}
```

Comment: To sort in java, you need a metric by which to compare objects by, which is done by an object's compareTo() method, which can be overriden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's build a comparator object:

```
static class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<PlayerScoreEntry> {
    public int compare(PlayerScoreEntry p1, PlayerScoreEntry p2) {
        // Do the work to compare p1 and p2.
        // If p1 is the winner, return -1.
        // If p2 is the winner, return +1.
        // If they really tied, return 0.

        // This is whatever the logic is to see if someone won outright,
        // plus the logic you've shown above that breaks ties.
    }
};
```

And then just sort the thing:

```
Collections.sort(playerScores, new ScoreComparator());
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch! Never really thought about using the Comparator class!

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own function to compare two objects and ask Java to use your function to sort the array of players.